# Select rows where a certain value doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Given a table like this:

```
SESS_CODE   YEAR    Count   ID
----        ----    ----    ----
D           2014    1       51
W           2014    1       51
            2014    2       51
O           2014    1       52
W           2014    1       52
            2014    2       52
D           2014    2       53
O           2014    1       54
W           2014    1       55
```

I'm trying to write to a query that returns rows where SESS_CODE = 'D', unless the ID is in another row where the SESS_CODE is something other then 'D'.  So the results should be:

```
SESS_CODE   YEAR    Count   ID
----        ----    ----    ----
D           2014    2       53
```

Comment: The sample data you posted only has one row with a `sess_code` of `D`.  Can you add a second row where the `sess_code` is `D` that you would want to be excluded from the results?  And explain to us why that second row would be filtered out.

Comment: Whoops, I guess I got a little overzealous when I was chopping down and anonymyzing. Edited so that `ID` `51` has a `D` `sess_code`, but shouldn't show up in the final results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3ade/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Data ( SESS_CODE, YEAR, "Count", ID ) AS
          SELECT 'D',           2014,    1,       51 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'W',           2014,    1,       51 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT NULL,          2014,    2,       51 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'O',           2014,    1,       52 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'W',           2014,    1,       52 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT NULL,          2014,    2,       52 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'D',           2014,    2,       53 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'O',           2014,    1,       54 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'W',           2014,    1,       55 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

One analytical function and a filter (no joins):

```
WITH Max_Sess_Codes AS (
  SELECT SESS_CODE,
         YEAR,
         "Count",
         ID,
         MAX( SESS_CODE ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DECODE( SESS_CODE, 'D', 1, 0 ) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ) AS max_sess_code
  FROM   Data d
)
SELECT SESS_CODE,
       YEAR,
       "Count",
       ID
FROM   Max_Sess_Codes
WHERE  max_sess_code = 'D'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3ade/10/0)**:

```
| SESS_CODE | YEAR | COUNT | ID |
|-----------|------|-------|----|
|         D | 2014 |     2 | 53 |
```

**Query 2**:

If you have a composite `UNIQUE` constraint on `SESS_CODE` and `ID` (i.e. if for each `ID` there can only be one row with SESS_CODE of `'D'`) then you could use:

```
SELECT MAX( SESS_CODE ) AS SESS_CODE,
       MAX( year ) AS year,
       MAX( "Count" ) AS "Count",
       ID
FROM   Data
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT( CASE SESS_CODE WHEN 'D' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END ) = 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3ade/10/1)**:

```
| SESS_CODE | YEAR | COUNT | ID |
|-----------|------|-------|----|
|         D | 2014 |     2 | 53 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from Table T1
where SESS_CODE = 'D'
    and not exists (select * 
                    from Table T2 
                    where T1.Id = T2.Id 
                        and T2.SESS_CODE != 'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE SESS_CODE = 'D' 
AND ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM table WHERE SESS_CODE != 'D')
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8ec6/1)